# For how many years has Picard been the commanding officer of a spaceship?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard, star-trek-picard

Picard has been in the captain's chair of at least 3 Federation starships, and serving as such for multiple years. He was the commanding officer of the *USS Stargazer*, the *USS Enterprise D*, and the *USS Enterprise E*.

For how many years has Jean Luc Picard been the commanding officer of a Federation starship?

I am looking for answers with canon sources.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213539/what-was-picard-doing-between-2455-the-loss-of-the-stargazer-and-2464-taking

Answer (score 18):

Picard (according to the [TNG Writer/Director's Guide](https://www.roddenberry.com/media/vault/TNG-WritersDirectorsGuide.pdf)) was in command of the Stargazer for 22 years. Since we know he lost command in 2355 (with the loss of the Stargazer), that places his taking command in 2333.

> **DATA:** *Captain, he may refer to an incident which occurred **nine years ago** in the Maxia Zeta star system, in which an unidentified starship*.

Picard assumed command of the Enterprise-D in [2364](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/126.htm).

> **RALPH:** What year is this?
> **DATA:** By your calendar two thousand three hundred sixty four.

The prior intervening nine years have never been discussed in canon. The EU novel "[The Buried Age](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Buried_Age)" suggests that he was commanding another (unnamed) vessel for at least some of this time, during which he met Tasha Yar and Geordi La Forge.

Picard remained in command of the Enterprise-D until its destruction in 2371. He assumed command of the Enterprise-E in 2373 where he remained in command until his [promotion to Admiral in 2381](http://picard.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/press-kits/s1-press-kit/picard-season1-press-book-05.jpg). It's reasonable to assume that he wasn't commanding a ship, nor would have have had command of a single vessel after that point, up until his retirement.

---

**Picard's total time in command of his three canonically known vessels is** *(22 + 7 + 8 =)* **37ish years**. If you factor in *possible temporary commands* he could have held between the destruction of his primary vessels, this may be as much as 42 years.

Comment: 22 + 7 + 6 = 35. Having said that, the Enterprise-E apparently spent almost a year in space on a [shakedown cruise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shakedown_cruise), prior to the events of _First Contact_ in 2373. So if we factor that in, the correct calculation is probably 22 + 7 + 7 = 36. Either way, you still got my upvote. :-)

Comment: @LogicDictates - I was factoring the extra months but you're not wrong. 35ish seems a more justifiable number than 36

Comment: [Ensign to Captain in 6 years](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard#Early_Starfleet_career)!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - He may have been a Junior Captain (e.g. a Commander or Lt Commander in charge of a vessel) for a couple of years

Comment: Is that ships' time or Earth time?

Comment: @I'mwithMonica - Good question. Picard and the crew spend a reasonable amount of time in various time loops.

Comment: "He assumed command of the Enterprise-E in 2373 where he remained in command until its destruction in 2379 during a pitched encounter with his clone Praetor Shinzon" - the ship was badly damaged but not destroyed. According to Memory Alpha, Picard was promoted and left the Enterprise in 2381

Comment: Stargazer, destroyed, Enterprise-D, destroyed, Enterprise-E, destroyed.  Hmmm, I'm sensing a pattern here.

Comment: @Peter M: Well, he wasn’t even on the Enterprise D when it was destroyed, and I still haven’t seen anything to confirm the Enterprise E was ever actually  lost, let alone with Picard in command

Comment: @Valorum My thoughts exactly. - But then again, does repeated time count as additional time? He might just have been captain for ~35 years, some of them multiple times...

Comment: @James - I assumed it was trashed at the end of Nemesis but apparently there were deleted scenes showing it being towed away and refitted.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica it's like working the night shift on the day we "fall back" from Daylight Saving Time to Standard Time - do you get paid for working 1am to 2am twice? (Sure you do, people would riot if they didn't, therefore we _should_ count any timeloop time twice.)

Comment: @PeterM The *Stargazer* was abandoned, not destroyed.

Comment: 1701-E wasn't lost in *Nemesis*. The film took place in 2379, and Picard is stated in background material to have left command of the ship in 2381 when he was promoted.

Comment: @Valorum: Actually, Nemesis shows the badly damaged Enterprise getting repaired in a spacedock towards the end in a non-deleted scene.

Comment: "he was commanding another (unnamed) vessel" - "Open hailing frequencies! This is Captain Jean-Luc Picard of the U.S.S. N/A."; "Sir, another vessel is dropping out of warp ... it's the TBD!"; "I served on the before I transferred here." Man, those unnamed vessels suck.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Really? I must have blotted out that memory.

Comment: @Valorum: [This](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis#Spacedock:_Earth) is the scene I'm thinking of, including the screencap.

Comment: @Valorum: Canonically (in the novels that go with Star Trek: Picard), the Enterprise-E is commanded by Captain Worf during the Romulan evacuation. As far as anyone knows, he’s still in command (Picard was pretty reluctant to contact any of them during the series)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which sources you check.

**50+ Years**

According to [this bio summary](http://picard.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/press-kits/s1-press-kit/picard-season1-press-book-05.jpg) Picard was in command of Starfleet vessels for **more than 50 years** and served in Starfleet during seven decades. Counting from his years at Starfleet Academy until he retired as an admiral (Entered the academy at age 18 in 2323, and retired in 2385.), he devoted 62 years to Starfleet.

The bio summary mentions these commands, which add up to 39 years.

- 22 years as CO of the *USS Stargazer* (2333 to 2355)
- 17 years combined as the CO  of the *USS Enterprise-D* and *USS Enterprise-E* (2364 to 2381)

Picard was CO of another vessel between his commands of the Stargazer and Enterprise-D, but we don't know which vessel he commanded during those years. He only mentioned it in [an offhand remark](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Federation_starships_(24th_century)#Picard.27s_starship) in the ST:TNG episode, *Legacy*. There are only 9 years between Stargazer and Enterprise-D, which is not quite the 11 more years required to say he was CO  for 50 years. That means Picard was CO of some vessel for at least 2 years after his promotion to admiral in 2381.

**From 39 to 47 Years**

Checking other sources gives different numbers.

- He was CO of the *USS Stargazer* from 2333 to 2355. (22 years)
- He was CO of an unnamed vessel between his commands of the Stargazer and Enterprise-D. (Length of tenure is unknown, but could be from 1 year to 9 years.)
- He was CO of the *USS Enterprise-D* from 2364 to 2371. (7 years)
- [This says](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard) Picard was CO of the Enterprise-E from 2372 to 2381. (9 years)
- Promoted to admiral sometime between 2381 and 2385, so he was probably not CO of any vessel during after his promotion.
- He retired in 2385. ([This page](http://picard.trekcore.com/gallery/albums/press-kits/s1-press-kit/picard-season1-press-book-05.jpg) says he retired in 2385, which was 14 years before his actions in the TV series, *ST:Picard*.)

The minimum number of years is 39. The maximum is 47.

Comment: The minimum number of years is 38, based on the numbers you listed (22 + 7 + 9). It appears Picard was not in command of a vessel between 2371 and 2372.